# Kuberenetes HPA scaling CPU/Memory based - facing issue on scaling behaviour

Tags: kubernetes, scaling, hpa

I have configured hpa with cpu and memory percentage and configured target value to 90% but still pods scaled up at ~50% memory usage.  Can anyone help me that how k8s default behaviour works with hpa in cpu and memory based scaling ?

Please find my hpa configuration.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: my-app
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.16.0
    helm.sh/chart: app-0.1.0
  name: my-app
  namespace: myservices
spec:
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        averageUtilization: 90
        type: Utilization
    type: Resource
  - resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        averageUtilization: 90
        type: Utilization
    type: Resource
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-app
```

Only tried with setting up desired count to 1 but still it was scaling to 4 pods.

Comment: How do you know it is scaling at 50%?

Comment: There are couple of service which uses less than 50% and running with  1 desired replica, also in one of the service I have allocated memory as 2.5*(Actually utilised memory), and I am able to achieve 1 desired pod for that service. For monitoring I am using grafana+prometheous